# Are weapon manufacturers investing in product placement?

Tags: product-placement

Basically in every movie or tv series we can find product placement. Companies like Apple, Microsoft, Samsung and many others are promoting their products through product placement.

Is it documented that weapon manufacturers like [Smith & Wesson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_%26_Wesson) or [Heckler & Koch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heckler_%26_Koch) are promoting their products in movies through product placement? And what are some examples of movies or tv series with product placement involving weapons?

I came to this question because in cinematic history there are some iconic weapons. For example Harry Callahan with his [Smith & Wesson Model 29](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_%26_Wesson_Model_29).

[image: Harry Callahan with gun]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entertainment Weekly did a [piece](http://www.ew.com/article/1999/06/04/where-hollywood-gets-its-guns) back in 1999 about gun product placement in film. Some companies participate by donating free weapons to prop houses. Other companies abstain from any kind of product placement.

Glock, Smith & Wessen, and Magnum are some of the top promoters to try and get their weapons into films.

> As improbable as it sounds, there’s an important moment in the ‘98 thriller U.S. Marshals. In the middle of their introduction, Tommy Lee Jones throws Robert Downey Jr. a withering stare and snarls: ”Get yourself a Glock. Lose that nickel-plated sissy pistol.”